# Maximize Print Width CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code that window prints the table (report) and the output looks like this:

[image]

***My code:***

**CSS**

```
  @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #reportArea, #reportArea * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #reportArea {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML (blade):**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success hidden-print" onclick="window.print();">
<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
</button>

<div id="reportArea">
      <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Room #</th>
              <th>Invoice #</th>
              <th>Client Name</th>
              <th>Booked At</th>
              <th>Reservation From</th>
              <th>Reservation To</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
          </thead>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($reservations as $res)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $res -> room -> room_number }}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ $res -> client -> name }}</td>
              <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> created_at )) }}</td>
              <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> reservation_from)) }}</td>
              <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> reservation_to)) }}</td>
              <td>{{ $res -> charge -> sum('price') }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><strong>{{ $total }}</strong></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
```

What can I do to maximize the use of the paper? As you can see there are big space in the left and right part.. or is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the element and the element parents' width

Comment: @takendarkk which part should I add a 100% width?

Comment: Whatever parts you want to fill up the whole page - the div, the table, etc...

Comment: Tried adding 100% to everything, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Just make its width 100%

```
#reportarea
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Or you can try this :

```
#reportarea
{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify page margings:

```
@page {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess the data is too short that's why